# Does Visual Studio or any add-ons provide Intellisense on injected concrete type for interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

With dependency injection in .NET core, I often find myself jumping to the startup.cs class to figure out what concrete type is being injected as an interface dependency in some other class.

So if I have a Person class:

```
public class Person 
{
public Person(ICellPhone phone){}
}
```

It would be neat if there was a tool that would let me click the contract in the constructor, press some key, and then auto navigate to what the current concrete implementation would be fulfilling ICellPhone.

Does anything like this already exist?

Comment: Right Click on interface and `Go To Implementations` ?